# How to use FFMpeg::create(); In PHP

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I want to create a web that can cut video now. If possible, try to use ffmpeg.
However, FFMpeg has been successfully used as a module, but FFMpeg :: create has not been used. How do I use FFMpeg :: create?

[image]

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video  = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
$video->filters()->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))->synchronize();
$video->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))->save('frame.jpg');
$video->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WMV(), 'export-wmv.wmv')->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'export-webm.webm');
```

Comment: What do you mean, by "has not been used"?

Comment: It means i installed ffmpeg and ffmpeg-php successfull , but ffmpeg-php object is not active

Comment: How do you see that an object is not active? Can you share the code you used so far?

Comment: require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
$video
    ->filters()
    ->resize(new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension(320, 240))
    ->synchronize();
$video
    ->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(10))
    ->save('frame.jpg');
$video
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\X264(), 'export-x264.mp4')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WMV(), 'export-wmv.wmv')
    ->save(new FFMpeg\Format\Video\WebM(), 'export-webm.webm');

Comment: And how do you see that something is not active? Does this code throw an exception?

Comment: FFMpeg::create() is not adapt. The page that generated this object did not work properly.